# Is every countable Dedekind domain the ring of integers of some number field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is every countable Dedekind domain the ring of integers of some number field? I tried googling different keywords, but did not find anything. Does anyone know of research in this area?

Comment: Dear LeBlanc, In addition to the counterexamples of Will Sawin, note that any localization of a ring of integers is again a countable Dedekind domain.  Regards,

Comment: As a general note, the ring of integers of a number field are a quite special type of Dedekind domain. E.g., for them each ideal class contains a prime ideal (and in suitable senses even the same number of them). In general this is *not* true.   

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope. $\mathbb F_p[x]$, $\mathbb Q[x]$, and all other affine algebraic curves over countable fields, are countable Dedekind domains. None are the ring of integers of a number field.